# Why can't I run the android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

I have installed everything like I was told to by the android website and all I keep getting after I create my avd is

```
"Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/christopher/Desktop/android-sdk-linux_86//tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory".
```

Anybody got any ideas??? I'm running linux if that helps.

Answer (score 28):

If you're running a 64-bit system, you need to install ia32-libs:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are running Ubuntu 13.10 x64 or the latest Linux Mint x64 then the `ia32-libs` package is not available anymore. The [solution](http://mem0ryleak.tumblr.com/post/64617476512/fix-android-adb-on-ubuntu-13-10-64bit) which worked for me without any problems is to:

`sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1`

Hope this will help!

Comment: For information about why `ia32-libs` has been removed, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package

Answer (score 1):

It's a lib32 problem, you need to install getlibs (http://frozenfox.freehostia.com/cappy/getlibs-all.deb) and run it against applications that do not work (e.g., adb and emulator).

Answer (score 1):

cmd from first comment didn't worked for me (Crunchbang linux) so I solved this problem with

*sudo aptitude install ia32-libs lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6*

Answer (score 1):

In directory `tools`, there are many types of `emulator`, while my computer works with `emulator64-arm`! My system is Linux Mint 16 amd64! Good luck!

```
./emulator64-arm @yxphone -sdcard yxsd -scale 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to that, and one in which you will not need to add archs or install anything, is going to the android-sdk install directory, and then to tools dir. There you'll find the emulator executable and plenty other emulator executables too.
Since the emulator file seems to actually be a chooser to which one of the others it will launch based on your OS arch (the problem is that the file itself is a 32bit executable), you can just rename it to emulator.old or something and then make a symlink named emulator to the correct file (mine was emulator64-x86 for amd64 arch). So...

```
cd (...)/android-sdk/tools/
mv emulator emulator.old
ln -s emulator64-x86 emulator
```

And it should work! The downside for this is that you'll probably have to do it everytime you update the SDK Tools and also will only fix the emulator, adb and some other tools will have the same problem! Anyways, still an alternative!

Answer (score 0):

64-bit system needs to install ia32-libs and it is working with latest Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon. I have used this. Just run Commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for me work fine

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```