# how do i configure my android emulator to start running in intelij?

Tags: android

I am getting this error whenever I try to run my emulator:

> Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/sypher/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: Does that entire path exist on your system? Possible you may find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631709/why-cant-i-run-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and as [harper89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750711/harper89) mentioned, I found the answer in this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631709/why-cant-i-run-the-android-emulator). I had to install the ia32-libs package. Assuming you are running a distro with apt:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Thanks, [hertzsprung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150884/hertzsprung).