# Cannot install ia32-libs (in order to run Android Emulator)

Tags: android

I am trying to start my Android Virtual Device(AVD), but I received the following error after I clicked "Start":

> Starting emulator for AVD 'MyAVD'
>   Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/ting/Desktop/android-sdk-linux//tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

I did some research and it seemed to point to I have to install ia32-libs since I have a 64-bit system. (according to [Why can't I run the android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631709/why-cant-i-run-the-android-emulator))

So I typed in "sudo apt-get install ia32-libs" in the terminal, and now this is what I got:

> ting@WTH:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
>   sudo: unable to resolve host WTH
>   [sudo] password for ting: 
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
>   ting@WTH:~$

Can anyone help?